# How to use same logic for multiple audioplayers on my page

Tags: javascript

I want to change playback speed for number of audio clips on the same HTML page.
The JS code for changing the speed goes like this:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function getPlaySpeed() {
  alert(vid.playbackRate);
}

function setPlaySpeed10() {
  vid.playbackRate = 1.0;
}
function setPlaySpeed09() {
  vid.playbackRate = 0.9;
}
function setPlaySpeed08() {
  vid.playbackRate = 0.8;
}
```

And HTML for audio is this:

```
    <audio id="myAudio" controls src="/home/../../../1-001.mp3"></audio>
                        <button onclick="getPlaySpeed()" type="button">What's the speed</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed10()" type="button">1</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed09()" type="button">0.9</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed08()" type="button">0.8</button>
<audio id="myAudio" controls src="/home/../../../1-002.mp3"></audio>
                        <button onclick="getPlaySpeed()" type="button">What's the speed</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed10()" type="button">1</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed09()" type="button">0.9</button>
                        <button onclick="setPlaySpeed08()" type="button">0.8</button>
```

So the speed actually changes only for the first  element.
I did change the id for the second element to myAudio1 and duplicated the JS code with the myAudio1 and this way both of them work, obviously :) but there should be better way!

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing the element id as a parameter in your functions will eliminate the need to duplicate your functions. The same thing can be applied to the speed as well.

```js
function getPlaySpeed(elementId) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(elementId);
  alert(vid.playbackRate);
}

function setPlaySpeed(elementId, speed) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(elementId);
  vid.playbackRate = speed;
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio-001" controls src="https://audionautix.com/Music/AshesOfAnEmpire.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="getPlaySpeed('myAudio-001')" type="button">What's the speed</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-001', 1.0)" type="button">1</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-001', 0.9)" type="button">0.9</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-001', 0.8)" type="button">0.8</button>

<audio id="myAudio-002" controls src="https://audionautix.com/Music/Assasins.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="getPlaySpeed('myAudio-002')" type="button">What's the speed</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-002', 1.0)" type="button">1</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-002', 0.9)" type="button">0.9</button>
<button onclick="setPlaySpeed('myAudio-002', 0.8)" type="button">0.8</button>
```

Note: replaced the audio files with something accessible so you can test this example live.

As required by license: music by audionautix.com